# Handling of throughput data using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-manipulation

I have multiple files containing throughput results from testing, I am wanting to plot the bandwidth over time for each file. I need to copy the data frame to excel so it can be plotted, is it possible to seperate the data and extract just the time and bandwidth? This is the format of the data I am loading into a dataframe. If it makes it easier I can remove the data up to the [ID] line.
I am using xlsxwtiter to build an excel document.
This is all the code I am using to simply load the txt file into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('...Results\Downstream\Throughput')
df = pd.read_csv('0_Downstream.txt')
print(df)
```

---

[  4] local 192.168.1.200 port 5001 connected with 192.168.1.10 port 35870

[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth

[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec  59.2 MBytes   497 Mbits/sec

[  4]  1.0- 2.0 sec  42.3 MBytes   355 Mbits/sec

[  4]  2.0- 3.0 sec  26.1 MBytes   219 Mbits/sec

[  4]  3.0- 4.0 sec  43.5 MBytes   365 Mbits/sec

[  4]  4.0- 5.0 sec  79.1 MBytes   664 Mbits/sec

[  4]  5.0- 6.0 sec  51.9 MBytes   436 Mbits/sec

[  4]  6.0- 7.0 sec  45.6 MBytes   383 Mbits/sec

[  4]  7.0- 8.0 sec  61.3 MBytes   514 Mbits/sec

[  4]  8.0- 9.0 sec  58.1 MBytes   487 Mbits/sec

[  4]  9.0-10.0 sec  66.4 MBytes   557 Mbits/sec

[  4] 10.0-11.0 sec  66.4 MBytes   557 Mbits/sec

[  4] 11.0-12.0 sec  68.0 MBytes   570 Mbits/sec

[  4] 12.0-13.0 sec  73.2 MBytes   614 Mbits/sec

[  4] 13.0-14.0 sec  77.0 MBytes   646 Mbits/sec

[  4] 14.0-15.0 sec  79.6 MBytes   668 Mbits/sec

Thanks.

Comment: So problem is parse text file to dataframe? What is separator? tabs, commas, whitespaces? It seems you need `df = pd.read_csv('0_Downstream.txt', header=1)` but wthout your real data it is hard answer. Is possible create sample of file, upload to gdocs, dropbox... and share link ?

Comment: You can use Python to plot data as well. The pandas package has some built in code for it, but matplotlib is the no 1 plotting package for Python.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4U4QibLufWbakRuejhhQm9oYkk
Here it's just a simple text file containing only what was shown in the question.